# MinGW - cross compile tool - latest version?

Tags: compiler-construction, cross-platform, mingw

At the [MinGW download page](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/) you can download the "Cross-Hosted MinGW Build Tool" which is a shell script to build the "MinGW cross-compiler" so that you will be able to compile your programs on "Linux" to the "Windows" target.

I have downloaded that script, run it and answered the interactive questions the script has asked me. I had to dowload some files from which one has name "**gcc-core**". And the "latest" version of the "gcc-core source code" I have found on that page, was "gcc-core-**3.4.5**-20060117-2-src.tar.gz" - so that "**3.4.5**" version.

But on "Ubuntu Linux" I can download the precompiled "mingw32" package which is of the version "**4.2.1**". How is it possible that the "Ubuntu package" version of MinGW is newer than the one from the MinGW "homepage"?

**So which is the latest version of the "MinGW cross compile tool"?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When cross compiling you have to build the toolchain targeting the platform you want it to generate executable code for, which means that you may do it without a script. You'll just need the sources of GCC (in this case).

Grab the sources, for example the ones for [GCC 4.4](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/GCC%20Version%204/Current%20Release_%20gcc-4.4.0/gcc-4.4.0-src.tar.bz2/download) and unpack them in a directory, then run `configure`, `make` and `make install`.

The following would be an example of a configure call targeting an i686 for Windows:

```
./configure --target=i686-mingw32 --host=$CHOST --build=$CHOST \
--prefix=/usr --enable-languages=fortran,c,c++ --enable-sjlj-exceptions \
--enable-hash-synchronization --disable-nls --disable-libssp --disable-shared
```